# Elasticsearch multi match with cutoff_frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use the "common query" with "multi-match" but I get unwanted results.
My original common query:

```
"query": {
    "common": {
        "_all": {
            "query": "the blabla",
            "cutoff_frequency": 0.001
        }
    }
}
```

This gives only results with "blabla" (since it is a low frequency) which is good.
But when I do this:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match" : {
        "fields": ["_all"],
        "query":    "the blabla",       
        "cutoff_frequency": 0.001
    }
}
```

I get many results with only "the" in them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize that when a common query is used inside a "match" query - the "operator" must be set explicitly to "and".